# How to enable IDE IntelliSense with dynamic imported python classes?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, intellisense

I have thousands of models in my package, each of them contains one class. Users can choose model they want to use by:

```py
from myproject.type1.models.m1 import m1
```

Very inconvenient.

The subfolder looks like:

```
type1/
├── __init__.py
├── constant.py
├── decorator.py
├── models
│   ├── m1.py
│   ├── m2.py
│   ├── m3.py
...
│   ├── m999.py
```

So I write a module loader to load module dynamic:

```py
class ModelLoader:
    def __init__(self, model_path):
        self.model_path = model_path
        self.models = {}

    def __getattribute__(self, __name: str) -> Any:
        try:
            return super().__getattribute__(__name)
        except AttributeError:
            if __name not in self.models:
                try:
                    model_file = import_module(self.model_path + "." + __name)
                    model = getattr(model_file, __name)
                    self.models[__name] = model
                    return model
                except ModuleNotFoundError:
                    raise AttributeError(f"Model {__name} not found")
            else:
                return self.models[__name]
```

With this, user can load module by just:

```py
models = ModelLoader(__name__.rsplit(".", 1)[0] + ".models")
m1 = models.m1
m2 = models.m2
```

But this cause a problem.

Vscode or pycharm can not provide IntelliSense for m1 if it is imported by `ModelLoader`.

Intellisense works:

[image]

not work:

[image]

How can I let IDE know class `ModelLoader` have a member `m1` and is defined in `myproject.type1.models.m1`?

---

I do not import all module in my package's `__init__` since it will harm user experience, it takes about 30s to import all models.

Comment: you can try and generate a `.pyi` file based on the `type1` directory. Pylance can use that to feed its static code analysis

Comment: @rioV8, it works! Can you write an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and generate a `.pyi` file based on the `type1` directory.

Pylance can use that to feed its static code analysis.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode uses static analysis for it's IntelliSense feature,
which means it analyzes the code without actually running it.

If you want to have intellisense support, you have to add the import codes at the beginning of your scripts like

`from myproject.type1.models import m1, m2, m3`

Add all the modules you want IntelliSense for.